# How can I change the program header in sap abap?

Tags: abap, sap-gui

I want to change the header name of the ABAP program. What can I do or where can I find the option to edit the header?

[image: Screenshot of an ABAP program in SAP GUI highlighting header text]

Answer (score 3):

Two ways for this:

- Set it in program options. Select the program and check menu Goto / Attributes.
- Or you can create a GUI title and set it via ABAP. This overwrites attributes' setting.

More about how to achieve: [here](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73ehp1/helpdata/en/d1/801d29454211d189710000e8322d00/content.htm).

Answer (score 1):

To change the program header is more easier than it seems.

Just open you program via **SE38 -> Goto -> Properties -> Check the title field and change -> Save**

And you are done. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have this.

[image]

Usually is changing the name in atributes with transaction se38, but sometimes this don't work, you need in the transaction se80, create a title GUI, if yuou don't have a title created, righ clic in the program name, create -> GUI title.

[image]

And put your name and code.

[image]

and in your program (se38) in PBO, you have to call the title with

`SET TITLEBAR '100'` (Put your title code)

(100 is the title code), but this instruction have to need inside of a moodle, if is outside don't will work.

I use the first moodle that i have in my PBO (i don't know if is the best decition or the right form, but is a way and works).

[image]

finally the title change

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The path is SE38 -> (Put Program Name) -> Now open the program in edit mode -> Select the option GOTO -> select Properties Change the program title.